# node.js instagram-web-api 2 factor login

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm using the API [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/instagram-web-api). What can I do to pass 2-factor authentication when logging in ?

Answer (score 0):

Use "passport JS" lib for node with expressJs it will help you in Instagram login and it would you help in many other **518 vendor** logins like google,fb,linkedin, github etc

http://www.passportjs.org/packages/passport-instagram/

Comment: passaport-instagram needs clientId as far as I can see. wasn't Instagram's official api service terminated?